# Getting java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannotserialize while passing array list of byte to web service using ksoap2 in android

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I have db file of about 5 mb in size ,  I have converted to byte array list and want to pass it to my web service for saving on server but I am getting can not serialize error. I am attaching my code below...

```
            SoapObject soap_request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);
            fileName = "DB"+UserID+"_"+backupDateTime+".db";

            PropertyInfo pi1 = new PropertyInfo();
            pi1.setName("_FileName");
            pi1.setType(String.class);
            pi1.setValue(fileName);
            soap_request.addProperty(pi1);

            PropertyInfo pi2 = new PropertyInfo();
            pi2.setName("_ByteArray");
            pi2.setType(ArrayList.class);
            pi2.setValue(data);
            soap_request.addProperty(pi2);

            PropertyInfo pi3 = new PropertyInfo();
            pi3.setName("UserID");
            pi3.setType(Integer.class);
            pi3.setValue(UserID);
            soap_request.addProperty(pi3);

            Log.v(TAG, "soap_request _FileName= >>"+soap_request.getProperty(0));
            Log.v(TAG, "soap_request _ByteArray= >>"+soap_request.getProperty(1));
            Log.v(TAG, "soap_request UserID= >>"+soap_request.getProperty(2));

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            //new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soap_request);
            envelope.dotNet = true;

            Log.v(TAG,"Calling webservice....");
            androidHttpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransportSE.debug = true;
            androidHttpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);

            Log.v(TAG,"Getting result from webservice....");
            SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result.getProperty(0).toString());
            Log.v(TAG, "Web Response...." + response.get(" Result "));

            if (response.get(" Result ").equals("Uploading DataBase Backup To Server successfully"))
            {
                flag = true;
                Log.v(TAG, "Database is uploaded .........");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

try Changing this

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
//new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);
```

To

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
new MarshalBase64().register(envelope); // this line is for serialization
```

Also you will get Better idea about your Problem from this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389105/runtimeexceptioncannot-serialize-error-to-send-byte-array-from-android-to-java) i guess.

Hope it will help you.